# Getting time since Unix epoch on both Windows NT and *NIX systems

Tags: c

The following snippet of C includes implementations for both Windows NT and POSIX-compliant systems to get the time (with microsecond resolution) since the Unix epoch. In the case of Windows NT, the time is registered as 100-nanosecond ticks since the NT epoch (1/1/1601), so it requires a bit of conversion.

I feel like this is the best solution I could've come up with, but it still feels a bit *clunky*. See if you can help:

````c
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(unix) || defined(__unix) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#include <sys/time.h>
static struct timeval lnm_current_time;
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
#include <windows.h>
#include <sysinfoapi.h>
static FILETIME lnm_win32_filetime;
#else
#error lognestmonster: Neither Windows NT nor a POSIX-compliant system were detected.\
        Implement your own system time functions or compile on a compliant system.
#endif


uint64_t lnm_getus(void) {
    uint64_t us;
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(unix) || defined(__unix) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    gettimeofday(&lnm_current_time, NULL);
    us = (lnm_current_time.tv_sec*1000000+lnm_current_time.tv_usec);
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
    // get system time in ticks
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&lnm_win32_filetime);
    // load time from two 32-bit words into one 64-bit integer
    us = lnm_win32_filetime.dwHighDateTime;
    us = us << 32;
    us |= lnm_win32_filetime.dwLowDateTime;
    // convert to microseconds
    us /= 10;
    // convert from time since Windows NT epoch to time since Unix epoch
    us -= 11644473600000000ULL;
#endif
    return us;
}
```
````

Answer (score 4):

Using static file-scope variables

```
static struct timeval lnm_current_time;
// ...
static FILETIME lnm_win32_filetime;
```

makes your code thread-unsafe: Two “simultaneous” invocations of your function from different threads access the same memory. (For other potential drawbacks of static file-scope variables see for example [Are file-scope `static` variables in C as bad as `extern` global variables?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/294737/83021) on Software Engineering.)

And there is no reason to use static variables here. With function local variables

```
uint64_t lnm_getus(void) {
    uint64_t us;
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(unix) || defined(__unix) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    struct timeval lnm_current_time;
    gettimeofday(&lnm_current_time, NULL);
    // ...
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
    FILETIME lnm_win32_filetime;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&lnm_win32_filetime);
    // ...
#endif
    return us;
}
```

the variables are defined exactly where they are needed, which makes the code easier to read and to argue about, and avoids the threading problem.

Answer (score 2):

In larger programs, lots of "compiler switches" (#ifdefs) make the code very hard to read, "clunky" if you will. It's not an issue in a tiny program such as this, but for larger programs you should consider a more "polymorphic" approach.

Like for example having a generic "epoch.h" as the platform-independent API. Link this with with a corresponding "epoch_unix.c" or "epoch_windows.c" file, where the C file contains everything OS-specific. Manage which one that gets linked using different builds and/or version control.

---

Some minor details:

- You forgot `#include <stdint.h>`.
- `lnm_current_time.tv_sec*1000000+lnm_current_time.tv_usec`. Make a habit of always declaring integer constants with a large enough type, no matter where they happen to be in an expression.

  That is, `1000000ULL`, or if you prefer `UINT64_C(1000000)`, the former giving type `unsigned long long` and the latter giving type `uint_least64_t`. The latter is ever so slightly more portable, but a bit harder to read.

Comment: The multiplication will implicitly convert from `int` to the appropriate type, won't it? (And it's *epoch*, not *epoc*.)

Comment: @S.S.Anne _Only_ if `lnm_current_time.tv_sec` is of an appropriate type. Which is hard to tell, you have to dig deep in documentation to find out just what `time_t` actually is.